# Location of System.Web.MVC so I can reflect over it with reflector

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I installed MVC 1.0.  Where's the System.Web.MVC dll so that I can use reflector to see how the helper methods are coded? I've looked in the bin folder of my ASP.NET MVC web app but it's not there.  I am not quite sure where the MVC 1.0 installer installs the dll and how that wires up to the web.config of your MVC apps.  Is System.Web.MVC installed in the GAC or something?  If so, how the heck can I reflect over the assembly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mine was in C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll.

Answer (score 4):

Mine is at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 1.0\Assemblies

Answer (score 3):

You can view the actual source code on-line at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/.  Sometimes the version there lags the release, but it's usually pretty up-to-date.  When I use Reflector, I just add the assembly from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 1.0\Assemblies`.

Comment: Actually you want http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com for stuff in core MVC (/aspnet is the samples tools etc)

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith that wasn't the url when I originally posted the answer.  Thanks for the reminder, though.  I've updated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to reflect any DLL referenced by your project, just right click on the DLL under References in Project Explorer, click Properties, and it will tell you the exact path.

Comment: however in this case, System.Web.MVC doesn't show up in properties of my web project in the assembly list

Comment: It should be in the list of references...  I only use web application projects, website projects may handle this differently...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has changed for VS2015/Windows10. Mine is under:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Web\Razor\v3.0\MVC5.1
```

**OR**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Stack 5\Packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45
```